# BBPress and Wordpress Responsive Video Embed Link

Tags: wordpress, video, iframe, responsive, bbpress

I am trying to allow users to embed videos in BBPress just by pasting links from Youtube. When I do so the videos appears but is cut off because the comment box  is to small to fit the iframe that is added to the site when WordPress adds the embed code. You can see an example here: http://b67.3d8.myftpupload.com/no-shift/topic/messed-up-divorce/

I did some searching and found some CSS that doesn't work either. Basically it adjusts the width but breaks on the height.

```
.bbp-reply-content {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25% !important;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.bbp-reply-content iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Is there a way to make the WordPress auto embed code responsive in BBPress?